# Suddenly cannot switch to YouTube account with no channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, user-accounts

I've just tried in my desktop browser (Firefox) to switch to the YouTube account with no channel. But it's not there on the list, only the three channel accounts which are associated with the Google account I'm logged into (Gmail address). On the other hand, the fourth (and original, existing since before I created any channels or was granted roles on any) account is visible in the Android app, as here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NArMU1L8do&t=15. How to do the same on desktop? Can I e.g. manually write some address which will cause it upon navigation?

Is this issue a known recent bug, hopefully to be fixed soon? Or a permanent new dictum from Google? Something else? Are they maybe planning to remove those accounts without channels, along with their viewing history and playlists (which I'd like to keep)?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user due to deleting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a way](https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher). Linking, if anybody needs it too.

Editor's note:

As of October 2023, the above-linked URL is redirected to the account **All Channels** page. The navigation path is Settings > Account > Add or manage your channel(s).